# Optimize reducer that sorts an object by a conditional on a parameter

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```js
reduceObjects = {
  uid1: {
    parameter: "good",
  },
  uid2: {
    parameter: "good",
  },
  uid3: {
    parameter: "bad",
  },
}

const reduceFunction = (reduceObjects) => {
  return Object.keys(
    Object.keys(reduceObjects).reduce(function(obj, key) {
      return reduceObjects[key].parameter === "good"
        ? { ...obj, ...{ [key]: reduceObjects[key] } }
        : obj;
    }, {})
  );
}

console.log(reduceFunction(reduceObjects));
/* [
 *   "uid1",
 *   "uid2"
 * ]
 */
```

This works fine, but it's an awful pattern. `reduceObjects` can be huge, and when I have 5k "good" objects the reducer function ends up creating and throwing away the first 4999 good objects before returning the final result.

The problem IMO is really this line: `{ ...obj, ...{ [key]: reduceObjects[key] } }`. Is replacing this with `Object.assign` enough? How can I avoid recreating new objects every time, and instead just accumulate the same object?

Comment: I figured as much which is why i asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get an array of every key which satisfies a predicate, why not use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```js
const reduceObjects = {
  uid1: { parameter: "good" },
  uid2: { parameter: "good" },
  uid3: { parameter: "bad" },
};

const reduceFunction = (reduceObjects) => {
  return Object.keys(reduceObjects).filter(key => reduceObjects[key].parameter === 'good');
};

console.log(reduceFunction(reduceObjects));
```